# Inkscape: Export individual objects as separate PNGs but retains the whole Page's size on each Image

Tags: inkscape, svg, export, png

Say for example  I have an svg image of a face. The `eyes`, `nose`, `mouth`, `ears` and `empty face` are different objects. I want to export each `objects` as their individual `PNG` image but, each image should have the same dimensions with the project itself.

Upon using the built-in batch exporter, this successfully exported each object as their own image. However the sizes/dimensions are dependent on the actual size of the object, it's not retaining the dimensions of the whole project (`500x500`).

[image: Batch Export panel]

Is there any way to export these objects with each image having the same size? (`500x500`). I want this so that on Unity, I could just place the images on top of each other and the objects will be on their proper places (`eyes`, `nose` etc). The problem with not having a "universal dimension" on each images is that I have to arrange them in Unity one by one again.

Any ideas? I'm also open to any plugin recommendations. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the batch exporter doesn't have an option to allow that.

Possible manual workarounds

1. If you don't mind exporting them one by one, you could use the Custom tab in the Export panel. Select each object in turn, make sure you choose "Export selected only", and change the file name each time. This is tedious, but doable.

or

2. Create new pages, one for each object you want to export. Draw a rectangle with no stroke or fill above your artwork snapped to the page boundary, select all, duplicate, and using snap to page borders, move the duplicated content onto the next page, duplicate and repeat. Then delete everything leaving only one object on each page. Finally, use the Batch Export Pages tab.